# Truncate table using prepare statements in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any way to write this PHP code in a secure way using Pepare statements?

```
 $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE comments";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query)
    or die('Error deleting table.');
}
else {
    echo "Sorry cannot delete";
}
```

I am trying to improve my Code but the '**TRUNCATE**' function of the database is giving me problems.

With this code lines it doesn’t work:

```
$table_commets = 'comments';
$PDOStatement_comments = $PDO->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE $table_commets;");
$PDOStatement_comments->execute();
```

Is there any way to improve it using **MySQLi prepare statements**?

Or it is better not to use Prepare statements in the TRUNCATE function?

Comment: There is **never** a case when you need a prepared statement for a truncate query. It means you are doing something awfully wrong. Either way just use a table nname explicitly written in your script, not taken from the user input.

Comment: @YourCommonSense okay, so I'll leave my code as in the first lines

Comment: Your first code is fine

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you